# Slow tracert between hops

Tags: networking, traceroute

Each hop in the tracert reports 2ms or less latency, but trying to get to the end of one hop to another goes really slow. What would cause the latency to be so low yet take so long to perform the hop?

Comment: What do you mean? The traceroute itself consuming too much time? Do you know how traceroute works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've seen slow traceroutes between hops when DNS can't properly resolve the IP address. Try adding a '-n' switch to your command. That will disable DNS lookup.

Comment: Looks like you meant -d, which worked.

Comment: its -n if you're using linux/unix, -d if you're on windows